# Non-rigid isomorphic structures

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, quantum-computing, query-complexity

In many of the problems trying to solve hidden shift over some objects like graphs mainly the rigid classes are considered. For eg. in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0510185.pdf) and [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0511148.pdf) isomorphism problem restricted over rigid graphs is considered. Consequently, hidden shift functions are injective. Although hardness for rigid structures also give hardness for class as a whole is there any other reason why this is done? Are hardness results like these also generalized for non-injective functions?